# Calculate the value of an interval

Tags: evaluation, estimation

I want to calculate the maximum absolute value of *- 2t* in the range *t∈{0,1}*, so I wrote the following code. However, when I ran the following code, an error was reported because I am not familiar with Mathematica, so I would like to ask how to rewrite my code?

```
Max[Abs[Evaluate[-2 t /. t \[Element] {t, 0, 1}]]]
```

Comment: For the sake of providing feedback, I can't understand the question. What is the relevance of the title to the post? Please rephrase and take a look at `Maximize` and other related functions.

Comment: @Syed Sorry, sir I didn't express myself clearly. My question is, I want to calculate the maximum value of 2t in the interval {t, 0,1}. How should my code be written?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps

```
Maximize[{Abs[ -2 t], 0 <= t <= 1}, t]
(*{2, {t -> 1}}*)
```